# Socket.io client ignoring port when namespace used [Bug?]

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have a simple node.js app with socket.io (1.3.5), taken from socket.io examples:

```
// Setup basic express server
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;

server.listen(port, function () {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});

// Routing
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

io.of('/admin').on('connection', function(socket){
    //handle conection on /admin namespace
});

io.of('/user').on('connection', function(socket){
    //handle conection on /user namespace
});
```

Now in my front-end I connect to these specific namespaces like so (again, taken from the example):

```
var admin_socket = io('/admin');
var user_socket = io('/user');
```

The app is running on port 3000 and the website is opened using URL `localhost:3000`.
When doing that I am getting CORS errors, it seems like Socket.io on client side is not auto-detecting the port number as soon as I start using namespaces (in firefox dev tools I can see requests going to `localhost/` rather than `localhost:3000/`).

---

If on my server-side I don't use namespaces:

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
    //handle general conection
});
```

And on front-end I connect this way:

```
var socket = io();
```

Everything works fine, port auto-discovery works and in firefox dev tools I can see connections being made to `localhost:3000/`.

---

Alternatively, if I still use namespaces on my back-end, and on front end I connect like so:

```
var admin_socket = io('localhost:3000/admin');
var user_socket = io(':3000/user');   //I can skip localhost
```

Again everything works (and indeed in firefox dev tools I can see network requests going to `localhost:3000/`).

---

How come the port auto-discovery is not working with namespaces? Is there a way to get it to work? Am I missing something here? Thanks.

---

See my answer below for a fix...

Comment: This bug was really annoying, wasn't there in any older versions of socket.io. Thanks for the fix!

Comment: Bug still extant in 1.3.6, where it consumed a day of my time. 

Many thanks for this write-up with fix - I had stalled on discovering it worked in the default namespace.

Comment: Can you move your *answer* out of the *question* and into an *answer*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so I did some debugging of code in socket.io.js and realized there is a potential bug there. On line 1050 a loc.hostname is used instead of loc.host.
This causes a hostname to be used when passing in a namespace, this doesn't include port number.
In case of no namespace being used, on line 1024 loc.host is being used and everything is fine.
I have taken a copy of the file and changed line 1050 to use host and everything works fine.
Found github issue with that, it is fixed in 1.4.x:
https://github.com/Automattic/socket.io-client/issues/812

Answer (score 0):

No need to mess with ports, it pretty much should work just by

```
var admin_socket = io('/admin');
var user_socket = io('/user');
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to get the auto port discovery to work without modifying the actual `Socket.io` code or waiting for a fix. The simplest thing you could do is just insert the current `location.port` including a colon before your namespace.

```
var admin_socket = io(':' + location.port + '/admin');
var user_socket = io(':' + location.port + '/user');
```

Or create a new function that will create a socket for you.

```
function sio(nsp) {
    return io(':' + location.port + nsp);
}
```